Stop games from turning on Intel Turbo/changing power plans
Long story short:
15% utilization 6-core i5 @ 4.3 GHz = 100C
100% utilization 6-core i5 @ 3.0 GHz = 80C
Intel processors are rated at 100C and I believe them cause I ran an i3 on a laptop for like 5 years, 8hrs/day at 90F+ but why push it if I don't need 26 billion operations per second?
I have disabled Intel Turbo in power settings by setting "max CPU" to 99%.  Except when many game aps launch somehow they bypass the Windows 10 power settings and once again turbo is enabled and the i5 starts running at 4.3 GHz even though it doesn't remotely need that much speed for these games, like Hearthstone - no reason it needs 4.3 GHz on a 6-core.
Hardware downclock occurs at 100C but this can cause briefs stutters which I don't appreciate and, it's at 100C as well so it "feels gross" even though Intel promises 100C is fine for the processor.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this behavior of games bypassing Windows 10 power settings?
Why does Windows 10 allow some apps to bypass the power plan when they are active window?  And is there a way to stop it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You may have an option to disable turbo boost entirely in your BIOS. It depends on your motherboard.

What processor do you have there is a bug in 13th and 14th processors that causes the processors to draw to much power.

You will want to [edit] your question with enough information that it can answer your question. For instance including what processor you have

Processor is an i5-8600k - pretty old at this point but I get the impression from numerous threads across the net it's not limited to one kind of intel turbo-enabled processor.  Additionally it's counterintuitive that activating most gaming software would bypass the turbo restriction in the Win 10 power settings and it simultaneously would be a hardware sourced problem other than the existence of "turbo mode" processors as a whole.

I've never heard of disabling Intel Turbo Boost simply by changing your power plan.
Disable it in BIOS
Since that's not working, you can try disabling it in the BIOS. That is what Intel details in their documentation for disabling Intel Turbo Boost. If you need to know how to get into BIOS or what setting to change, consult the manual for your motherboard or the manufacturer. Usually you press the Del or F2 key when booting to get into BIOS.
Limit maximum processor frequency
Another solution (from reddit) is to limit the maximum processor frequency. To enable this option, edit the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\75b0ae3f-bce0-45a7-8c89-c9611c25e100

Change attribute from 1 to 2 to unhide the maximum processor frequency setting in power options.

Then in the power settings, choose a frequency that produces thermals that work for you.

